# JSON.Parse not support in IE8 in Datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-8, datatable

I am using the datatable v1.10.0 that is not working in IE8. IE8 gives error that "JSON" is undefined.

Comment: What versions of everything else are you using? A little sample code and HTML will avoid your question being closed.

Comment: I am also agreed with TrueBlueAussie, yet i have posted an answer check if this solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a separate library for this for IE legacy browsers. JSON 3 is a modern JSON implementation compatible with a variety of JavaScript platforms, including Internet Explorer 6, Opera 7, Safari 2, and Netscape 6. The current version is 3.3.2.

- [Development Version (43 KB; uncompressed with comments)](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.js)
- [Production Version (3.5 KB; compressed and gzip-ped)](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js)

JSON 3 exposes two functions: stringify() for serializing a JavaScript value to JSON, and parse() for producing a JavaScript value from a JSON source string. It is a drop-in replacement for JSON 2. The functions behave exactly as described in the ECMAScript spec, except for the date serialization discrepancy noted below.

The JSON 3 parser does not use eval or regular expressions. This provides security and performance benefits in obsolete and mobile environments, where the margin is particularly significant.

#### [For more info go here: https://github.com/bestiejs/json3](https://github.com/bestiejs/json3)

---

You can include it with IE comment inclustion format something like this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <script src="json3.js">
<![endif]-->
```

above will be executed for IE browsers only.

Comment: great and glad to help you @RaviAgrawal.